# Selenium wire running very slow

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumwire

Selenium wire is running very slow for me, like takes 30 seconds to run the code.
I am using selenium wire together with undetected_chromedriver.v2
the settings I am using are :

```
seleniumwire_options = {
   'proxy': {
       'http': 'http://user:pass@host:port',
       'https': 'https://user:pass@host:port',
   },
   'disable_encoding': True
}
option = ChromeOptions()
option.headless = True
option.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument("--headless")
driverChrome(use_subprocess=True,options= option, seleniumwire_options = seleniumwire_options)
```

Wanted to note that I want to use selenium wire for proxy only.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
options = {
    'disable_capture': True  # Don't intercept/store any requests
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#limiting-request-capture